# KDB/Q Question on Parsing a string and concatenate

Tags: kdb

| InstanceID | OrderID | Strategy | Fills |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NG1 | jhbubuy-ClientName1-2022-07-01 | VWAP | 5000 |
| NG2 | nb8yvce-ClientName2-2022-07-01 | POV | 300 |
| NG1 | cebciube-ClientName3-2022-07-01 | TWAP | 1000 |

Hi guys have the table above as an example. I am beginner in KDB/Q so please bear with me. Any guidance would help.

1.) I am trying to parse OrderID by "-" and create a new column "ClientName" based on what I parsed on OrderID

| InstanceID | OrderID | Strategy | Fills | ClientName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NG1 | jhbubuy-ClientName1-2022-07-01 | VWAP | 5000 | ClientName1 |
| NG2 | nb8yvce-ClientName124-2022-07-01 | POV | 300 | ClientName124 |
| NG1 | cebciube-ClientNameABC-2022-07-01 | TWAP | 1000 | ClientNameABC |

2.) Create a new column by parsing OrderID then concatenate it with a separate column called InstanceID.  So it creates a InstanceID_OrderID

| InstanceID | OrderID | Strategy | Fills | InstanceID_OrderID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NG1 | jhbubuy-ClientName1-2022-07-01 | VWAP | 5000 | NG1-jhbubuy-2022-07-01 |
| NG2 | nb8yvce-ClientName124-2022-07-01 | POV | 300 | NG2-nb8yvce-ClientName124-2022-07-01 |
| NG1 | cebciube-ClientNameABC-2022-07-01 | TWAP | 1000 | NG1-ClientNameABC-2022-07-01 |

Answer (score 3):

To get desired table you should:

1. Use [`vs`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/vs/) operator to split OrderID by "-"
2. Get second element of each sublist for ClientName
3. Remove second element from each sublist, prepend InstanceID and  join new list using [`sv`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/sv/) operator for InstanceID_OrderID.

If the table has following structure:

```
t: flip`InstanceID`OrderID`Strategy`Fills!
  (`NG1`NG2`NG3;
  ("hbubuy-ClientName1-2022-07-01";
     "nb8yvce-ClientName2-2022-07-01";
     "cebciube-ClientName3-2022-07-01");
  `VWAP`POV`TWAP;
  5000 300 1000);
```

The next query does the job:

```
update
  ClientName: {("-" vs x) 1} each OrderID,
  InstanceID_OrderID: {x: "-" vs x; "-" sv enlist[y],(1#x),2_x}'[OrderID;string InstanceID]
from t
```

where

1. anonymous function `{("-" vs x) 1}` splits `OrderID` by `"-"` and chooses index 1
2. `{x: "-" vs x; "-" sv enlist[y],(1#x),2_x}` splits `OrderID` by `"-"`, chooses 0 and 2+ indices (there is no remove by index operation in Q), prepends InstanceID and joins everything into "-" delimited string

Comment: For the second part you haven't joined the InstanceID to the front of the new OrderID

Comment: Pardon, I've missed it. The answer was updated to include InstanceID.